# Ubuntu 22.04 no_proxy seems to be ignored

Tags: networking, network-manager, proxy, environment-variables

Proxy has been configured using both the System Settings UI for Network Proxy and the environment variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` (and also the uppercase versions).

The environment variables have been made persistent in either `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` or `/etc/environment` (one or the other, not both at the same time, and power cycling after changes to ensure settings scripts are utilized).

Experimentation has also been conducted by overriding the environment variables on command line.

What has been tried in a nut shell:

```bash
# doesn't work
curl 192.168.0.1

# still doesn't work
export NO_PROXY=192.168.0.0/16
export no_proxy=$NO_PROXY
curl 192.168.0.1

# HTTP port is accessible
nc -zvw 1 192.16.0.1 80

# works!
curl --noproxy '*' 192.168.0.1

# works!
unset HTTPS_PROXY https_proxy HTTP_PROXY http_proxy NO_PROXY no_proxy
curl 192.168.0.1
```

Where I state "does not work" above, the proxy replies rather than the HTTP server.

Furthermore this is not limited to curl. The proxy settings set via the UI are used by Firefox, yet only by setting the IP in the "No proxy for" list in firefox's own settings can the 192.168.0.1 server be reached.

As such it pretty much feels like 22.04 does not use NO_PROXY and no_proxy the same way older versions did, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Firefox, I have found the uninstalling the snap version and installing via apt made a difference regarding http_proxy env vars

Answer (score 1):

proxy variables are some kind of nightmare.
`no_proxy`: This variable should contain a comma-separated list of domain extensions proxy should not be used for

so try

```
printf -v no_proxy '%s,' 192.168.{1..255}.{1..255};
export no_proxy="${no_proxy%,}";
```

Comment: I did know that already. The actual system has a csv list of host names, subnets and domains. Where the domains are preceded with a dot e.g. `$ export no_proxy="192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8, myserver, .mydomain.co.uk"`

Comment: yes, and the subnet entries do not work. just try the fist line and you will see the difference.